# QuickQ newbie: Admob, do I have to remove test device ids or does it not matter?

Tags: android, admob, android-xml

So yeah by using ads:testDevices="" I've added a few test devices of mine to see if my Admob adverts worked. Now I've done all the testing and I want to release my application.

Is it imperative to remove that line of code from my XML layouts? I mean really it's only going to effect those devices right?

Can I just go ahead and release the app? Keeping the test line in?

Quick question I know, I just want to be sure since I have a lot of layouts and what is a small issue may be a lot of work.

Is there any downside to leaving the ids in basically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ads:testDevices` only sets those whitelisted devices to test mode, so all other devices will get live ads. So it is fine to leave this line in your app.

Comment: Thank you. Makes my life a lot easier too. +1 and accepted answer.